# Angular ngStyle not working on ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-style

I want to auto resize a ui-grid using the ui `ui.grid.autoResize` module but the ngStyle never applies

I have done [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/91CGIWpehcWnvKSoaYbO) to show what I mean

Comment: do you want to set height for row element?

Comment: No, I want to dynamically change the style of the ui-grid div with ng-style, but it does not work properly, even with a 'manual' changing of the style: cf. the `angular.element` and `byQSelector.style.height` ligns (45 & 47)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found. I have done a bad ng-style declaration `ng-style="{{myStyle}}"` instead of `ng-style="myStyle"`

Answer (score 0):

Autoresize works to resize the grid to the size of the container - it deals with resizes of your window.  It doesn't resize the grid to the size of your data.

Comment: The problem is that the ng-style changes never apply to the real style of the ui-grid div